# How to add multiple language in .vscontent file?

Tags: visual-studio-2012

Hey Is there anyone who can explain me about .vscontent file.

Here I tried for multiple snippet to add in vscontent.

**can we add multiple language in one vscontent file ??**

```
<VSContent xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/vscontent/2005">
<Content>
    <FileName>copyright_cs.snippet</FileName>
    <FileName>copyright_css.snippet</FileName>
    <FileName>copyright_html.snippet</FileName>
    <FileName>copyright_js.snippet</FileName>
    <FileName>copyright_sql.snippet</FileName>
    <FileName>copyright_xaml.snippet</FileName>
    <FileName>copyright_xml.snippet</FileName>
    <DisplayName>Copyright Text</DisplayName>
    <Description>Inserts copyright information</Description>
    <FileContentType>Code Snippet</FileContentType>
    <ContentVersion>2.0</ContentVersion> 
    <Attributes>
<Attribute name="ProjectType" value="Visual C#"/>
<Attribute name="lang" value="csharp"/>                 
    </Attributes>           
</Content>
</VSContent>
```

but it import only c# snippet.